# New column with the count of columns that meet certain criteria

Tags: r, dplyr

I searched a lot and I could not find a good solution for this simple problem. I tried `rowSums`, but with no success.

I have a `df` like the first image. I want to create a new column (`V4`), preferably using `tidyverse`, with the count of rows that meet a certain condition. In this example, the condition would be `. == 5`.

[image]

How many times number 5 appears in the other columns:

[image]

Example df

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = c(1,2,5,5,3),
                 V2 = c(1,5,5,5,5),
                 V3 = c(1,3,4,5,1))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `rowSums` on a logical matrix

```
df$V4 <- rowSums(df == 5)
```

---

If we want a dplyr solution

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
   mutate(V4 = rowSums(cur_data() == 5))
```

Or may also use `reduce`

```
library(purrr)
df %>% 
   mutate(V4 = across(everything(), `==`, 5) %>%
           reduce(`+`))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another `dplyr` option:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(V4 = sum(c_across(V1:V3) == 5, na.rm = TRUE))
```

**Output**

```
     V1    V2    V3    V4
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     1     1     1     0
2     2     5     3     1
3     5     5     4     2
4     5     5     5     3
5     3     5     1     1
```

Or another option using `purrr`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(V4 = pmap_int(select(., everything()), ~ sum(c(...) == 5, na.rm = T)))
```